# Meaning of "Ever written"

Tags: grammar

Can anyone explain me the meaning of " most beautiful language ever written" .What does "ever written" mean?

Comment: Please include a reasonable amount of context.   Was there the word "most" ahead of "beautiful", for instance??

Comment: sorry, Yes it is.  Sentence is "Most beautiful language ever written

Comment: So what does "most beautiful language" mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from a dictionary, a focus on **ever** reveals:  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ever)

> - at all times; all the time and on every occasion
> - at any time

One can have ever busy, ever sung, ever composed and in your sample: **ever** ( at any time in knowm history) **written**.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of the word **most** being immediately before **beautiful**, the phrase *ever written* expresses that it is the most beautiful language to ever exist.